# convert static character array to dynamic

Tags: c, dynamic, arrays

Given a static array how to change it into dynamic allocation with `arr` as `a pointer unsigned`:

```
char arr[] = {1,4,5,8,9,6,4,3,2,1,5,7};  
unsigned char *arr = NULL;
```

Now how to assign this value to `arr`.

I am new to programming please help.

Comment: Why did you tag it C++ then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) to dynamically allocate the array and use [`memcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) to copy the contents. Remembering to [`free()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) what was `malloc()`d.

Comment: is there a way to directly assign the values to pointer? as i will need to replace the static declaration.

Comment: @user1660982 Yes, but you were asking for dynamic allocation.

Comment: yes i want to use dynamic allocation also.

Comment: @user1660982, do want to create a dynamically allocated copy of the array or do you want to access elements of the array via a pointer?

Comment: @hmjd i want to create a pointer . i have some static values like {1,2,3,4}. i want to store these static values in that pointer

Answer (score 1):

The most C++ way would be to use a `std::vector` instead of a raw allocated array:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> dynArr(arr, arr + 12); //where 12 is array size
```

If you really need a dynamically alloated raw array, use `std::copy()`:

```
unsigned char *dynArr = new unsigned char[12];
std::copy(arr, arr + 12, dynArr);
```

Comment: @psur I answered when the C++ tag was still there...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
char arr[] = {1,4,5,8,9,6,4,3,2,1,5,7};
char *pArr = arr;
```

Now you can access the first element as:

```
*pArr
```

second element as:

```
*(pArr+1)
```

for instance

also you might want to give [this tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) a read.